# На открытом балуне яндекс.карт отсутствует возможность перетаскивать карту

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Когда в API Яндекс.Карт открываешь балун на метке, то вся область, которую он занимает становится "мёртвой" для перетаскивания карты т.е. вне области балуна можно делать drag, а на самом балуне можно только текст выделить. Как отключить такое стандартное поведение и сделать возможным перетаскивание карты даже при протягивании мыши над балуном.

Answer (score 1):

Можно задать опцию [interactivityModel](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#Balloon__param-options.interactivityModel) . Это то как балун будет пробрасывать события на карту. Варианты интерактивности [существуют такие](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/interactivityModel.storage-docpage/).

Также можно его расположить ниже слоя событий с помощью [опции pane](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#Balloon__param-options.pane), чтобы на балуне ничего не выделялось к примеру,  варианты пейнов [указаны тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1-dev/ref/reference/map.pane.Manager-docpage/)

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [54.83, 37.11],
        zoom: 5
    }, {
        balloonInteractivityModel: 'default#layer',
        balloonPane: 'places'
    });

// Открываем балун на карте (без привязки к геообъекту).
myMap.balloon.open([51.85, 38.37], "Содержимое балуна", {
    // Опция: не показываем кнопку закрытия.
    closeButton: false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/24o5rh6b/